# html css: how to draw dotted box around <div>?

Tags: html, css

I saw in SO there is a lot of DIV which is surrounded by dotted lines, how to do it in CSS & HTML?

Thanks.
Bin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div style="border: dotted 1px black" id="mydiv">content</div>
```

or

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #mydiv { border: dotted 1px black; }
</style>
```

Comment: is it possible to specify which sides has borders? eg) I want the top, left, right side have borders, but I don't want the bottom side has border, is it doable?

Comment: yes, you can use border-left: dotted 1px black; or border-right, same for border-top and border-bottom

Comment: thats' cool, thanks John. I hope you have gotten out of drunk.

Comment: @bin nope, still drinkin it up, rum & coke = awesome, i'm sure in a few days you'll get the hang of css and be writing all kinds of cool stuff.